# 関数引数でのrefパターンがmoveを生じさせる理由を知りたい

Tags: rust

Rust言語では `ref` パターンを使って右辺の式の参照を暗に取る事ができると思います。

```
// Copyではない適当な型
struct Val{
    value: u32
}

fn main() {
    let x: Val = Val { value: 32 };
    let rx1: &Val = &x; // 普通に参照を取る
    let ref rx2: Val = x; // 参照を暗に取る
    let ref rx3: Val = x; // 何度でも取れる
    println!("{}", x.value); // 単に参照をとっているだけなのでmoveされておらずxは使える
}
```

この文法を関数引数で使ってみます。

```
struct Val {
    value: u32
}

// refでとってみる
fn test(ref v: Val) {
    println!("test: {}", v.value)
}

fn main() {
    let x: Val = Val { value: 32 };
    test(x); // しかし残念ながらここでmoveされていて
    test(x) // コンパイルエラー(value used here after move)
}
```

しかしこの場合は引数はmoveされてしまい、二度使う事ができません。
こういう形でrefを使った場合にxがmoveされる理由をご存知の方がいたら教えて頂けませんか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`let x: Val`のとき`test(x)`とすると、関数の引数は「値渡し」になります。値渡しでは、値が関数の引数の領域へmoveします。

`main`ではスタック領域上に`x`のための領域があります。

```
mainのスタックフレーム
  x    | Val { value: 32}
```

`test`を呼ぶと、まず`main`の`x`の値が、`test`の引数の領域（`arg0`としました）にmoveします。

```
testのスタックフレーム
  v    | 初期化されてない状態
  arg0 | Val { value: 32}

mainのスタックフレーム
  x    | 初期化されてない状態（move済み）
```

そして`v`には`arg0`への参照が置かれます。

```
testのスタックフレーム
  v    | &arg0
  arg0 | Val { value: 32}

mainのスタックフレーム
  x    | 初期化されてない状態（move済み）
```

これを擬似的なコードで示すと、以下のようになります。

```
fn test(arg0: Val) {
    let ref v = arg0;
    println!("test: {}", v.value)
}
```

このように動作しますので、`x`の値がmoveするわけです。

参考： https://users.rust-lang.org/t/ref-and-for-function-arguments/12790

Comment: ありがとうございます。一度スタックフレームにmoveされるというのは、なるほどという感じです。言語デザイン的にはこの辺の決定にはいろいろありそうですね……。